# A valid latin/english personal name using REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I've made this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/YZFThW/1):

```
^[A-zÀ-ú]{3,} [A-zÀ-ú]{3,}.*
```

to validate latin/english names.
The idea is that the person should have at least two names with 3 characters each.

The problem is that the way I did, it won't process names like `Maria da Mara` or `Laura D'Avila`

So how can I enforce that

1. All characters are valid latin Alphabet plus `'`
2. There are at least two names with three characters, one should be the first and the other does not matter what position is

How to solve this puzzle?

Thanks

Comment: What about all of the names that have two letters? What is requiring you to enforce incorrect rules about names? Also, `[A-z]` includes several non-letter characters (look at an ASCII table).

Comment: I am afraid that *any* assumption about human names is false. Better use something like `[\p{L}\p{M}. '-]+` (Unicode assumed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios your Regex does not cover.

1. It does not match `'`, you can simply add it to the characters list you match.
2. "Maria da Mara" has 2 characters. Perhaps reduce the minimum number of characters in the second match group.

```
^[A-zÀ-ú]{3,} [A-zÀ-ú']{2,}.*
```

You can add a named capture group as well to take the first word as the first name and any subsequent match as the last.

```
^(?<first_name>[A-zÀ-ú]{3,}) (?<last_name>[A-zÀ-ú']{2,}.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/YZFThW/2

Comment: Is it possible to instead finish with any character (.*), make this regex allows only the allowed characters? Because this accepts Robert Davila 2323232 for instance

Comment: @JLCDev yes it does, you can remove it no problem. I was just going off of your usage. The `{2,}` range will take up to any number of characters that are valid in `[A-zÀ-ú']`

Comment: but without the .*, it will match only two words and not at least two worlds

Comment: @JLCDev I see what you mean. You can use this `^(?<first_name>[A-zÀ-ú]{3,}) (?<last_name>([A-zÀ-ú']{2,}\s?)*)`. I've updated it with your last example https://regex101.com/r/KoOpJO/1